# Stream one STDIN over websocket to multiple clients

Tags: linux, unix, websocket

Currently i have "streamgenerator" in Linux which outputs data to stdout/namedpipe etc. I found websocketd online which is kind of close to what I need but problem is it spawns new process for every client that connects.
What i am looking for is to stream same data (single process producing data to stdout) to multiple clients.

```
$ websocketd --port=8080 ./streamgenerator
```

Will create new streamgenerator process for every new connection to websocket. What I want is one instance of streamgenerator and output from it copied for all clients.

Is there some simple way? Only thing that comes into my mind right now is writing C program which will take STDIN into buffer of size X and for each client have pointer into that buffer (which points to where client was able to read until that point).... If client connects he will start getting just the new data... If client too slow... his "READ" pointer will fall out of buffer his connection will just be dropped since he can't keep up.

My question is is there any way without developing this tool? First i thought piping to named pipe and then make websocketd read from it... but that will of course not work because first client of websocket will read data and throw them away...

Comment: Wouldn't streaming data from STDOUT risk the first message's integrity? i.e., if the connection is initiated in the middle of STDOUT outputting a JSON object, only the last part of the JSON will be sent... or am I missing something?

Comment: That's a thing I will handle at client side Javascript... After connection throw away bytes until you see next message beginning... You can imagine it like a video stream.... Connect anytime and just wait for next iframe... However in this case is not related to video...

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`websocketd` source code](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/blob/ac4b25f80b5b9abd4e6b904738dedfb196e2ca2b/libwebsocketd/http.go), it seems to use a process based server (a new process per connection).... I'm not a GO programmer, so I'm not sure I'm reading it right, but the [README](https://github.com/joewalnes/websocketd/blob/9ba8d6429d0aef60cebd928d0ab27b083ea1e377/README.md#details) seems to indicate the same concept.

Hence...

> problem is it spawns new process for every client that connects

This can't be avoided. The design means that new connections are inherently forked, along with their STDIN and STDOUT. Data streamed to the original STDIN isn't accessible from within the new connection...

... so using a single `streamgenerator` with `websocketd` isn't an option.

> Only thing that comes into my mind right now is writing C program...

I think this might be the only way to avoid the multi-process design.

You don't have to use C for this. You could probably use Ruby or node.js just as easily (they will probably be easier to author, while you'll pay for convenience with a performance hit).

> My question is is there any way without developing this tool?

I don't think so.

However, [facil.io](http://facil.io) could make it fairly simple to author a C web socket tool that broadcasts data using it's native Pub/Sub API (allowing you to easily scale, in the future, using Redis)... but being the author, I'm biased.

#### EDIT

Here's a short Ruby script that will broadcast data from the pipe to any connected web socket connection (data separated by lines).

File `script.rb`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'iodine'

class Example
    def self.call(env)
      if env['upgrade.websocket?'.freeze] && env["HTTP_UPGRADE".freeze] =~ /websocket/i.freeze
        env['upgrade.websocket'.freeze] = Example.new
        return [0,{}, []] # It's possible to set cookies for the response.
      end
      [404, {"Content-Length" => "12"}, ["Bad Request."] ]
    end 

    def on_open
        subscribe channel: :stream, force: :text
    end
    def on_message data
        close # are we expecting any messages?
    end
    def on_close
        # nothing to do
    end
    def on_shutdown
        # server is going away, notify client.
    end
end

Iodine::Rack.app = Example

# remove these two lines for automatice, core related, detection
Iodine.processes = 1;
Iodine.threads = 1;

# initialize the Redis engine for each iodine process.
require 'uri'
if ENV["REDIS_URL"]
  uri = URI(ENV["REDIS_URL"])
  Iodine.default_pubsub = Iodine::PubSub::RedisEngine.new(uri.host, uri.port, 0, uri.password)
else
  puts "* No Redis, it's okay, pub/sub will still run on the whole process cluster."
end

# Create the loop that reads from ARGF (the pipe)
# defer threading because we might fork the main server
root_pid = Process.pid
Iodine.run do 
    puts "Starting to listen to pipe"
    if(root_pid == Process.pid)
        Thread.new do
            ARGF.each_line do |s|
                Iodine.publish channel: :stream, message: s
                puts "read:", s
            end
        end
    end
end

# start iodine
Iodine.start
```

You can use it from the terminal using:

```
$ streamgenerator | ruby script.rb
```

This is just a dirty example, but it sows how easy this could be.

Oh, it requires [the `iodine` gem](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine), which is fail.io's port to Ruby (also mine).

**EDIT 2**

I added a bit of code that allows you to use Redis with the example code I provided and limits the publishing to a single process.

The Redis engine is native to facil.io (it's in C, with a Ruby bridge for iodine) and you can use it to send commands as well as Pub/Sub.

If you're using Redis to scale across a number of machines, I would consider splitting the script into a publisher script and a server application.

Also, you only need Redis if you're using more than one machine. If you run Iodine with `Iodine.processes = 8`, the pub/sub engine would still work.

Iodine has a bunch of other features, if you need them, such as static file service etc'.

You can also package the whole thing in a middleware and make it part of an existing Rails/Sintara/Rack project using iodine as the server (for Websocket support).

...

As for:

```
  $ ./streamgenerator | pub --channel "redisstream"
  $ websocketd --port=8080 sub --channel "redisstream"
```

It sounds like this will mitigate the issue, although I think `websocketd` will still open a new process per connection, which uses more resources than an evented "reactor pattern" such as the one used by servers such as nginx (and iodine, passenger, puma and a bunch of others).

Comment: That's so far best solution. Easier than writing custom C code and it is in Ruby which i use&&like.  
Searching around what you suggested i found there is Pub/Sub command-line tool for Redis.  
Therefore i should be able to do something like this:
  
    $ ./streamgenerator | pub --channel "redisstream"  
  
and on the websoketd side:  
  
    $websocketd --port=8080 sub --channel "redisstream"  

my biggest issue with this is it's written in haskell which is making it black box for me :(

Comment: @underhood - I added optional Redis pub/sub to the example code. You only need Redis if you're using more than a single machine. It's really just a couple of lines of code. Iodine also offers some command line arguments (such as `p` for `port` etc'). If you enjoyed my answer, feel free to up-vote ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. Shouldn't this do the trick:

```
streamgenerator | tee fifo1 | tee fifo2 | tee fifo3
```

Comment: Yes that is something in right direction... However how you connect it to websocketd? How you create 'tee split' everytime client connects? How i understand websocketd is it executes command given as parameter and forwards its STDOUT trough websocket. Problem is it does so for every client... I need streamgenerator to run only once since is resource heavy. Note websocketd as the websocket server is not fixed... it's just closest solution i found without needing to implement custom tool.